How to use self hosted Lightning node?
Looking for some guidance... I followed the Raspibolt guide, and completed setting up my own Bitcoin Node, Electrum Personal Server, and Lightning Node.
I have the Electrum Mobile Wallet, and I am able to connect to my node both at home and outside of home. This is primarily what I wanted to achieve. However, I am interested in being able to user my own lightning node as well, both at home and outside, and here's where I am getting confused.
I've wrapped my head around a light wallet being able to talk to my instance of Electrum Personal Server. But the Lightning node has its own wallet, so... Can I open a channel from my Electrum wallet TO the Lightning Node I'm running? If so, how do I do that?
Do I need to restore the Lightning wallet being used by LND in Electrum Wallet to be able to open channels?
